# Integration of exponential having ||Lx|| inside?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, variance, exponential-distribution, integral

I am stuck with performing this integration. Can anyone help please?

$$
\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}[M_j] \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\mathbb{E}[M_j^2] =
e_j^T
\left(
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} m^2 \pi^D_{\text{prior}}dm
\right)
e_j \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\gamma^2 e_j^T \left(L_D^T L_D\right)^{-1} e_j
$$

The $e_j$ is called: canonical basis
$$
\pi^D_{\text{prior}}(m) \propto \exp
\left(
  - \frac{1}{2 \gamma^2} || L_D m ||^2
\right)
$$

Comment: Why do you need to integrate it?

Comment: I want to estimate the variance as shown in Fig.1

Comment: but then see that the term with the integral in it is followed by an equality (with $\text{def}$ above it, presumably indicating a definition). So it seems there's nothing to integrate, you just use the formula at the end. Someone integrated it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. I know that it is done. I am asking about the middle steps between?!!

Comment: So it's not that you want to estimate the variance (see your previous response to me)  -- for which you could just use the formula -- but that you want to *derive* the result. Clarifying that issue (what you ultimately wanted to achieve) is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably by $m^2$ you mean $mm^\top$ since $m$ is a vector. The integral computes the second moment matrix of a zero-mean multivariate normal distribution whose covariance is $\gamma^2 (L^\top_D L_D)^{-1}$. Since it is zero-mean, the second moment matrix is the covariance matrix. Write

$$\pi^D_{\mathrm{prior}}(m) \propto \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} m^\top \left[ \left( \frac{\left[ L_d^\top L_D \right]}{\gamma^{2}} \right)^{-1} \right]^{-1} m \right).$$

Just compare this to the density given on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) of the multivariate normal.